# How to change api's JSON parameter with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

I have an api and it has a JSON like,

```
[{"NAME":"john","SURNAME":"johny","ADULT":"3","CHILD":"3","BABY":"0",}]
```

Inside my js function, I want to send request to web service that will change the "BABY" to "1".Is there any way to do that without using JQuery?

Comment: do you want to modify the BABY attribute to 1 in client side? or do you want to send the entire JSON to server for it to change and return the updated JSON to you?

Comment: Do you want to change 'BABy' before sending the request or something else?

Comment: Yes I want to send the entire JSON to server with new BABY value.

Comment: This problem can't be solved by client-side javascript. You need to change the API itself, on server. If that is not an option for you then you can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regular javascript array, including a regular javascript object. I', not sure if I got you right, but to change the baby in the snippet you posted, all you need to do is access it and change it :

```
// responseDate === [{"NAME":"john", ... ,"BABY":"0"}]
responseData[0].BABY = '1';
```

Comment: I did this before but it doesn't change the api when I refresh the link.

Comment: Yeah of course it doesn't. Your API is reading something from a database in some server, somewhere. you cannot change whats in it, with javascript, inside your browser. If you're using an open API, read the documentation, maybe there is an update API, which you can send a request to update baby in the database, if you or one of your colleagues have written the API, well, write another API that accepts an input to update that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `arr[0]` to access that object in the array. Since, the data type of `BABY` is string value `1` so use `arr[0].BABY = "1"` instead `arr[0].BABY = 1`.

```js
var arr = [{"NAME":"john","SURNAME":"johny","ADULT":"3","CHILD":"3","BABY":"0",}];

arr[0].BABY = "1";
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What I want to do is changing the api content,not assigning it to variable and change the variable.I need to change it within the API.